# android custom layout doesn't align correctly in gridView

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having an layout issue where i have a custom layout I use in a gridView in which a checkbox is suppose to align at the bottom right corner of an imageView. The preview of the layout shows it looks correct but when it loads into the gridView it moves the check box to the top left of the imageView. I have tried making the image smaller in the gridView and also removing the spacing in in between objects in the gridview, but to no avail.

here is my custom layout for each item of the gridView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgThumb"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imgThumb"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgThumb"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgThumb"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the gridView layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grdImages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSelect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is an image of what i would like the item in the gridview to look like, and this is also what the preview shows it will look like [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPZdC.png)

and this is what happens in the actual gridView [GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lORU8.png)

Comment: i can add a couple pictures if it helps anyone understand my issue. Thanks for the consideration.

Comment: Try LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout for the Custom Layout.

Comment: i have also tried that but i could not figure out how to get the check box to be at the bottom right corner of the imageView. I tried gravity="top|end" but that puts it outside the imageView

Comment: Please attach images.. and if there is no restriction on using a particular type of layout try using Framelayout instead of relative layout.. set the layout_gravity for checkbox to right|bottom

Comment: What is Your problem can You explain shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgThumb"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue occured because you do not set alignment for your ImageView.
Just set alignParentTop=true for ImageView.
Then, align the Checkbox below the ImageView by set its property layout_below point to ImageView's id.

Or, replace RelativeLayout by LinearLayout with orientation is vertical, since you have set ImageView witj fixed size.

Comment: i just tried your idea and had no effect. thank you!

Comment: I see, you have to set fixed size for the parent layout too.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: `android:layout_marginStart="xdp"` being x a logical number for your case (can't say anything without seeing any image) to the xml bloq for the checkbox.

By the way, you should be using [constraint layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) to avoid these kind of problems! And, if you already are, you just forget to constrain the checkbox.

Good luck.

Comment: this does work for me except I am worried it will have a different alignment for different sized phones. I am looking for a nicer and simpler solution I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

custom_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgThumb"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity"center"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: this worked great as well but the alignment was a little off but thank you for your input i will definitely look into FrameLayout more to learn about them!

Comment: @Shawnzey you are welcome.. Please upvote if it helped

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imgThumb"
 android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="100dp"/>
<CheckBox
 android:marginTop="80dp"
 android:id="@+id/chkImage"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgThumb"/>
```

Comment: this does work for me except I am worried it will have a different alignment for different sized phones. I am looking for a nicer and simpler solution I suppose.

Comment: Oh, I never thought about supporting a wide range of screens. Maybe there's someone has the better solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Custom Layout.This may help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/icons"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gridImg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```